# Webdriver unable to catch exception when browser is forced to quit (python)

Tags: python, debugging, exception, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a series of test over webpage. I use Webdriver for this and I try to detect a moment, when browser (Firefox) is forced to quit in gui for example. When it happens, I get a very long and ugly traceback.

Main program executes the test suite in separate thread. For example this code:

```
def urlopen(self, url):
    ''' Opens browser driver and redirects it to specified url addresss. It web driver
    is not initialized, it tries to initialize it at first.
    '''
    # check webdriver initialization, if broken or not initialized, can be fixed

    try:
        self.redirectToBlank(self.driver);
    except (urllib.error.URLError, AttributeError): # User closed web driver or is None

        try:
            self.initDriver()
        except:
            raise

    # !! this is the moment, when I close the browser window

    # if there is a problem with URL loading, it cannot be reapaired
    try:
        self._driver.get(url);
    except:
        print("Webdriver crashed or was forced to quit!", file=sys.stderr)
```

this method for opening the browser. `initDriver` method initialize `self._driver`, which is an instance of `webdriver.Firefox`

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 165, in urlopen
    self._driver.get(url);
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 176, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 162, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 355, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 402, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 487, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1268, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1253, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 1143, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 354, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\http\client.py", line 324, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 637, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\Python33\lib\threading.py", line 594, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 361, in runFromStart
    self._run()
  File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 369, in _run
    self.units[0]() # run self.test_openBrowser()
  File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 418, in test_openBrowser
    result = self.webtester.urlopen(self.url)
  File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 168, in urlopen
    log.warn("Webdriver crashed or was forced to quit!", file=sys.stderr)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1778, in warn
    warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1773, in warning
    root.warning(msg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Python33\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1244, in warning
    self._log(WARNING, msg, args, **kwargs)
TypeError: _log() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

I don't quite follow, why the `try-except` doesn't catch any exception, which is thrown. I think the first exception is relevant, but if you need code of methods mentioned in the second part of traceback, I'll add it.

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st traceback:

```
File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 165, in urlopen
   self._driver.get(url);
```

2nd traceback:

```
File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 361, in runFromStart
   self._run()
...
File "c:\Users\david\workspace\tester\sdi\testing.py", line 168, in urlopen
   log.warn("Webdriver crashed or was forced to quit!", file=sys.stderr)
```

your `try-except` has a problem with the logging statement.

however I don't think you can catch an exception from another thread, you would have to catch it in its own thread and e.g. use message queues to notify the main thread.

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal. `try-except` block handles only the exception, which occured in the same thread. Then for communication with main thread I use a queue. The problem, what I have missed, is that I do the synchronization using the queue, but in this case, I write into a log file from both threads, that is the problem. Thanks again for making me realize!